# How to statically call one staticmethod from another (in the class body)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, static, static-methods

How do I *statically* (i.e. *in the class body*) call a `staticmethod` which calls another `staticmethod` in Python 3.6?
I would like to use a `staticmethod` to initialize a static member of my class. The problem is that I'm trying to refer to my class *before* it has been created (unlike in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1859959/1072869)).

Below is an example of my problem. I was actually trying to initialize a static dictionary using dictionary comprehension which makes use of a static function, so I've included an example of that too. I managed to solve that using a basic loop, but there are also [other ways](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11786352/1072869) to use comprehensions statically.

```
class Test:

    @staticmethod
    def something(q):
        return q + 10

    @staticmethod
    def foo(x):
        return "Hello {0}".format(Test.something(x))

    # **** foo is called, but throws error at call to Test.something() ****
    #print(foo.__func__(4))    

    # something() is also used by itself.
    print(something.__func__(2))



    # My problem involved initializing a dictionary. Solved using loop.
    a = [1,2,3,4]

    #d = {k: "yup" for k in a}          # Dictionary comprehension works
    #d = {k: Test.something.__func__(k) for k in a}     # Error, Test/something not defined

    d = {}
    for k in a:
        d[k] = something.__func__(k)   




print(Test.foo(5))  # Works, class defined (but not what I need).
```

EDIT: This does not appear to be a duplicate of [Calling class staticmethod within the class body?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12718187/calling-class-staticmethod-within-the-class-body). This question is explicitly asking how to call one staticmethod *from another* in the class body, whereas the other question only asks how to call a staticmethod within the class body.
(In any case, the best solution seems to be to do away with the staticmethod and use a module-level function instead)

Comment: Python 2 or 3? But really, my advice would be just *don't use `staticmethod`* sounds like a use case for a `classmethod`, or better yet, just a couple of module-level functions

Comment: As for your `d` attribute, just add it directly to you class outside the definition...

Comment: Python 3, and i've just figured out a simple way to initialize my dictionary, edited. 
How would I use a `classmethod` for this? It still needs the class to be defined already I think. Thanks

Comment: No, you use the first argument to the `classmethod` to refer to the *class*. That's the whole point. But again, you probably don't even want methods at all, just normal functions.

Comment: If you are in Python 3, you can use `__class__` inside your `staticmethod` decorated methods to statically call *another* static-method. But again, I urge you to simply use normal functions.

Comment: So for example I create a `classmethod` `bar` which takes `cls`, the class, and `x` as a parameter. How would I call this *statically*? Both `Test.bar.__func__(x)` and `bar.__func__(Test, x)` don't work.

Comment: Uh, are you  trying to call it *in the class body*? I was answering how "to statically call one staticmethod from another". But again, for like the millionth time, **just use normal functions**.

Comment: Yeah I am, I thought that was what calling something 'statically' meant - in the class body. I'll edit the question. What do you mean by 'normal functions'? I don't want to do this for instance variables, I specifically want to initialize a static member using static functions which call other static functions. Thanks
EDIT: I just saw that you said 'module-level functions'. I understand now, cheers. I'd still like to know if there is an answer to this question. If possible, could you elaborate on how to use `__class__` to do this? I can't figure it out.

Comment: `__class__` is simply to refer to the *class itself* inside a method in Python 3. It wasn't how you would do it from the *class body*, which is really a weird thing to do.