# how to access a python method within a class from a staticmethod within the same class

Tags: python, methods

I need to execute a method from a @staticmethod within the same class: the following code returns an error:

NameError: global name 'self' is not defined

```
class Main:
    def __init__(self):
        self.start = 0

    def prints(self, message):
        print (message)

    @staticmethod
    def sendMessage(message):
        self.prints(message)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main = Main()
    main.sendMessage('Testing to print from staticmethod')
```

could someone give me an idea, how to access the prints methods from the statimethod. thank you

Comment: This is a clear indication that `sendMessage` should *not* be a static method.

Comment: Btw. possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1859959/static-methods-how-to-call-a-method-from-another-method I have no flags left for today

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't access not static class members from a static method. Static means, that you do not need to generate an instance of the class. Therefore you could use static methods without having an object of the class. Without having an object the non-static member function is never generated and therefore you can't call it. There exists no `self` in a static scope.

You would have to make your `prints(message)` method static as well to access it

Comment: Either way, making `prints` static makes it available in the `sendMessage` method. Doesn't matter which way around.

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing like this, then you need to initiate class inside of static method and pass the variable you want to print or other stuf. There is no other way for it.

Answer (score 0):

```
@staticmethod
def sendMessage(message):
    Main.prints(None, message) # Prefixing with Main so prints can be found.
```

When a static method is called, the caller doesn't pass itself (also, the caller won't be an instance of the class). This is why `self` is not defined in your code.

To reference prints, use `Main.prints`. And to call it, fit the argument list: when prints is called statically, there is no instance reference to pass as the `self` argument, so explicitly passing something else (`None` in my example) forces it to work.

This will make the code run, but you probably be mixing static and non-static methods like this. Also, in your code, `sendMessage` is being called from an instance. To call it statically would look like: `Main.sendMessage('...')`.